# Jaxb2 catalog file with relative paths

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, jaxb2, catalog

I'm trying to generate some Java code from quite a lot XSD's. Most of them work quite nicely, however I have trouble with one specific XSD which imports another XSD with a relative path. An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xmpl="http://example.com/this/is/namespace" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/this/is/namespace">
    <include schemaLocation="../../0301/required.xsd" />
    <some> ... xml ... </some>
</schema>
```

This is an anonymised XSD because of the client, of course. However, I have already build the other XSD which it is referring to in another module. Which is working great by the way. So now I want to resolve the include, but I'm currently unsuccesful. I have tried different and multiple catalogs, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="public">

    <public publicId="required.xsd" uri="maven:com.geodan.imgeo:stuf!stuf0301!stuf/stuf0301.xsd" />

    <public publicId="../../0301/required.xsd" uri="maven:com.project.example!module!folder/required.xsd" />

    <public publicId="http://example.com/this/is/namespace/required.xsd" uri="maven:com.project.example!module!folder/required.xsd" />

    <public publicId="http://example.com/this/is/namespace/../../required.xsd" uri="maven:com.project.example!module!folder/required.xsd" />

    <public publicId="http://example.com/stuf0301.xsd" uri="maven:com.project.example!module!folder/required.xsd" />

</catalog>
```

and

```
--
  Standard Catalog test file for Imgeo
--

PUBLIC "http://example.com/this/is/namespace/required.xsd" "module/src/main/resources/folder/required.xsd"

PUBLIC "../../0301/required.xsd" "module/src/main/resources/folder/required.xsd"

PUBLIC "0301/required.xsd" "module/src/main/resources/folder/required.xsd"
```

But it just won't work. Anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the maven-jaxb2-plugin project has an open issue on this subject:
 [Allow rewriting system ids for local files #19](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/19)